# Laravel ORM relationship method 'BelongsToMany' throwing error

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4

**Summary**

I am receiving the following error when trying to call the relationship:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
>   could not be converted to string

My setup is very basic, and consists of two models, `User` and `Role`.

**User Model [User.php]**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface {

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $hidden = array('password');
    protected $fillable = array('id', 'username', 'password');


    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

**Role Model [Role.php]**

```
<?php
class Role extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = "roles";
    protected $fillable = array(
        'id',           
        'code',
        'name'
    );

    public function foo() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'map_role_user', 'role_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

And finally I'm calling the method `foo` in the routes file, example:

```
Route::get('role', function() {
        return Role::find(1)->foo();  
    });
```

Comment: try this `Role::find(1)->foo`

Comment: That was exactly it. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships or https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

If a collection is cast to a string, it will be returned as JSON:

```
<?php
$roles = (string) User::find(1)->roles;
```

Comment: I'm a dope! Thanks! I've spent an hour just staring at that. Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, roles returns `user` plus the data in the pivot table, `map_role_user`, but not the `role`. I would need to iterate manually, is that correct?

Comment: User::find(1)->roles is going to return all the data about the roles but nothing about the user. If you need the info of the user and the roles, you can do $user = User::find(1) and then you can use $users as a Collection and call $users->roles to show the data about the roles of that user.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to add further constraints to the query then you have to use `dynamic properties` concept. So,

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->posts as $post) {
    //
}
```

If you want to add more constraints then do this

```
App\User::find(1)->posts()->where('title', 'LIKE', '%Best%')->get()
```